# Change title of automatically generated form view in Odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8

I want to change the heading of form view in the grey area. (Check image below.)

This should have to be changed from SHIP00001 to some other name or field. Is that possible?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name in the form view is gotten in two ways

1. From a field which you specified `name` of the field (i.e `name = fields.Char('Field name')`)
2. and when you set `_rec_name` to some other field or you override `_name_get` to set a custom name

so what you can simply do is set

`_rec_name` to another field in your model

That's the name that will show up the form heading or in the drop down field of any other model where you have a relation to it.

Comment: i set the _rec_name = 'field name' in model, its working for me now, thank you for information.

Comment: @TayyabJaved that's good to hear, don't forget to accept my answer if it fully answered your question :)